# Angular - Getting property from json object and displaying it as image

Tags: angular

I'm having a problem with displaying a image from json that is located on api online.
Excuse me for my poor angular skills, I just started it 2 weeks ago.
I'm trying to access "image1" property from "data" object in json file.

I've tried using reader to read from url and it worked well, but retrieving from api - specifically json's object "data" and property "image1" seems to be a problem. Maybe problem is that my approach is wrong with just setting src to the "data" object, I need to set it to data["image1"], I've tried setting to `[src]="data["image1"]` but with no success.

My JSON

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "type": "car",
    "name": "Porsche 911",
    "description": "driving machine",
    "area_id": null,
    "data": {
      "name": "JSON Name",
      "description": "JSON Description",
      "image1": "https://unsplash.com/photos/u6BPMXgURuI"
    }
  }
]
```

My interface Car

```
export interface Car {
  id: string;
  type: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  area_id: string;
  data: string;
}
```

My component html

```
<tr *ngFor="let i of cars | async">
        <td>{{i.id | json}}</td>
        <td>{{i.type | json}}</td>
        <td>{{i.name | json}}</td>
        <td>{{i.description | json}}</td>
        <td>{{i.area_id | json}}</td>
        <td><img [src]="i.data | json" alt="image"></td>
      </tr>
```

My component ts file

```
export class CarComponent implements OnInit {

  cars: Observable<Car[]>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cars = this.http.get<Car[]>('https://car-garage-             
beta.herokuapp.com/api/cars/porsche');
  }
}
```

In my interface if I set "data" type to string or object I get the same **error**

```
net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

Comment: _In my interface if I set "data" type to string or object I get the same error_ hard to believe that if you set that property to Object, or event better, the specific properties of your JSON, you will get that net error.

Comment: I think that was because I just retrieved "i.data | json" instead of "i.data.image1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bind image like this in your *ngFor

```
<td><img [src]="i.data.image1" alt="image"></td>
```

and In  your interface  set "data" type to any

Answer (score 0):

As Ved_Code_it says, bindind [src] to i.data.image1 works:

`<td><img [src]="i.data.image1"></td>`

### Explanation

By `[src]` we can see:

- the html tag **image** has a attribute named **src**.
- It is wrapped by brackets **[ ]**: This is Angular one way binding. Which means that
  whenever the value assign to [src] changes the src property of the img element will change too. (If you change the value of i.data.image1 from the javascript, your image will change)

Here I leave some advices for a new angular programer:

- In your interface Car, you define `data: string;` but what you really expect is an object so you should change it to
  `"data": {
    "name": string,
    "description": string,
    "image1": string
  }`. This is typescript type definition, and helps the programer not to commit errors but, in the end, when it transpiles to javascript, this code disappears.
- It would be convenient to check that attribute *data* exists and it has *image1*.

Answer (score 0):

app.compoenent.html

```
<div *ngIf="item.icon" class="img">
    <img [src]="item.icon">
</div>
```

my JSON:

```
{
    id: 'App',
    title: 'App',
    type: 'item',
    icon: '.assets/img/sidebar/app.svg'
},
```